# iOS : Why am I getting 'Unused variable' in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables, warnings

I'm coding to display a **php** `echo`

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:180.0]; 
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/signup/getkey.php"]]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection    sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When I compile, I have this warning message : `Unused variable key`

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you don't do anything with `key`. You simply alloc and init it, but never really use it.

You could do something like `NSLog(@"%@",key);` and the error will go away.

The other option is to set `Unused Variables` to warnings. Go to your project target, Build settings, then find the below image and change `Unused Variables` to `Yes`. This will change it from and error to a warning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the last line you are assigning key to a value but you never use it.  You can configure it to not throw an error, but rather a warning if you do not use a variable.  Otherwise just comment out the assignment of key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use the key, simply comment it out by //

```
// NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection    sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```